# Add class to newest items that are added into the array to indicate that they are new

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am making a chat app with AngularJs and I have a function to add a new conversation with dummy data (for testing). And when there is a new conversation it adds the class "new" to the element. But when I add another new conversation it add the class to the newest element and it gets removed from the other new element that was added.

When there is a new conversation it should add the "new" class to the element (not in the array but in the HTML) and when you add another new conversation it has to add a new class to that element as wel but keep the other new class on the other element.

I have found this [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/Eb2kR/) and used it. The problem is that when I add another new conversation it removes the "new" class of the other new conversation.

Here is my code:

```
conversationList.newest = "";
conversationList.addConversation = function() {
    var conversation = {
        ConversationID: conversationList.newId(),
        Person   : {
            name  : "Bobi Ristov",
            email : "bobby.ristov@socialdeal.nl",
            time  : Date.now(),
            image : "http://lorempixel.com/276/276/people/",
            phone : "06 - 12345678"
        },
        Messages : []
    };
    conversationList.newest = conversation.ConversationID;
    conversationList.conversations.push(conversation);

};
```

And sample of the array:

```
conversationList.conversations = [
     {
        ConversationID: 1,
        Person   : {
            name  : "Bobi Ristov",
            email : "bobby.ristov@socialdeal.nl",
            image : "/img/bobi.png",
            phone : "06 - 12345678"
        },
        Messages : [ {
                         text         : "Ik heb een vraag",
                         messageClass : "user-message",
                         time         : 1429257762800
                     },
                     {
                         text         : "Wat is je vraag?",
                         messageClass : "admin-message pull-right",
                         time         : 1429257942900
                     },
                     {
                         text         : "Hoe kun je een deal kopen?",
                         messageClass : "user-message",
                         time         : 1429257763000
                     },
                     {
                         text         : "Door middel op de 'Koop nu' knop te drukken",
                         messageClass : "admin-message pull-right",
                         time         : 1429259943100
                     } ]
    },
     {
        ConversationID: 2,
        Person   : {
            name  : "Rene Jaspers",
            email : "rene@socialdeal.nl",
            image : "/img/rene.png",
            phone : "06 - 87654321"
        }
        ,
        Messages : [ {
                         text         : "This is a second user message",
                         messageClass : "user-message",
                         time         : 1429257762500
                     },
                     {
                         text         : "This is a second admin message",
                         messageClass : "admin-message pull-right",
                         time         : 1429258942900
                     } ]
    },
     {
        ConversationID: 3,
        Person   : {
            name  : "Jafeth van Gorp",
            email : "jafeth@socialdeal.nl",
            image : "/img/jafeth.png",
            phone : "06 - 12348765"
        }
        ,
        Messages : [ {
                         text         : "This is a third user message",
                         messageClass : "user-message",
                         time         : 1429257763000
                     },
                     {
                         text         : "This is a third admin message",
                         messageClass : "admin-message pull-right",
                         time         : 1429257944000
                     } ]
    },
     {
        ConversationID: 4,
        Person   : {
            name  : "Peter Covers",
            email : "peter@socialdeal.nl",
            image : "/img/peter.png",
            phone : "06 - 87654321"
        }
        ,
        Messages : [ {
                         text         : "This is a fourth user message",
                         messageClass : "user-message",
                         time         : 1429257763000
                     },
                     {
                         text         : "This is a fourth admin message",
                         messageClass : "admin-message pull-right",
                         time         : 14292579444000
                     } ]
    }
];
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How long do you want to keep this new class? That is, if I insert two, three, or four rows, are they all red, or...? The fiddle you posted is only keeping one item in `$scope.lastInsertedId`, so, if you want multiple, simply keep an array of items.

In [this modification of the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bt2xcadk/) I changed your markup from:

```
<span ng-class='{lastinserted: item.ID==lastInsertedId}'>
```

To:

```
<span ng-class='getClass(item)'>
```

And in your controller, I changed `$scope.lastInsertedId = ""` to `$scope.newItems = []`

Now just insert the `ID` of the item new into `newItems`, and in `$scope.getClass()` check if your item is in that array:

```
$scope.newItems= [];
$scope.addItem = function(){
   var dd = new Date($scope.itemDate);
   var item = {"ID":$scope.items.length+1, "heading":$scope.itemName, "date":dd.getTime()};
   $scope.items.push(item);
   $scope.newItems.push(item.ID);
}

$scope.getClass = function(item) {
   var isNew = false;

   $scope.newItems.forEach(function(id) {
       if (id === item.ID) {
           isNew = true;
       }
   });
   return {
       lastinserted: isNew
   };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried your code, but I got an error:

Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$parse/syntax?p0=(&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%3A%5D&p2=10&p3=%7BgetClass(item)%2C%20active%3Aonversation.ConversationID%20%3D%3D%conversationList.current.ConversationID%7D&p4=(item)%2C%20active%3A%conversation.ConversationID%20%3D%3D%conversationList.current.ConversationID%7D

Comment: Post it in a fiddle.  It works int he fiddle I posted.

Comment: I would like to put it in a fiddle but it is to much code. I tried it now and it's not working in the fiddle. I think the error comes from this: <br/> `<div class="row conversation" ng-class="{getClass(conversation), active: conversation.ConversationID == conversationList.current.ConversationID}" ng-click="setConversation(conversation.ConversationID)" ng-repeat="conversation in Conversations | orderBy: '-Messages[Messages.length -1].time'">` <br/> I am not sure if I can use it like this

Comment: You should be able to create the least amount of code required to reproduce your issue in a fiddle -- you don't have to put all of your business logic.  If you can't reproduce your issue in a fiddle, we certainly can't.  With that, you definitely can't have your `ng-class` how you have it.